# How to create variables dynamically based on a string array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, variables

I have a string array `Globals.stringArray` that populates a list of controls based on the amount of entries in the array. I want to track how many times the control is used (eg. a button clicked) with an integer that I will use and display at a later time.

I assume that a dynamically created global variable is needed depending on how many controls are created (based on how many items in the string array).

Secondly, how would I do this and how would I access these variables afterwards?

Here is what I have:

```
Public Shared Sub dynamicVariables()
    Dim variables As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    variables("MyDynamicVariable") = Globals.stringArray.Length
End Sub
```

I am assuming that I can add the `dynamicVariables()` into where my buttons are created to have it run in conjunction with that and map the variables to the buttons?

EDIT: (with suggestions)

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddNewButton()

End Sub

Public Sub AddNewButton()

    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100

    For Each item As String In Globals.candidates
        Dim btn As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
        btn.Location = Location
        btn.Text = item
        btn.Width = 150
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.buttonClick
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        buttonTop += 20
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub buttonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Did you select {0} ?", btn.Text), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Dim usage As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        If usage.ContainsKey("myButtonName") Then
            usage("myButtonName") += 1
        Else
            usage.Add("myButtonName", 1)
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No pressed")
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

EDIT 2: (with suggestions)

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub From2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        AddNewButton()

    End Sub

    Public Sub AddNewButton()

        Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100

        For Each item As String In Globals.candidates
            Dim btn As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
            btn.Location = Location
            btn.Text = item
            btn.Width = 150
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.buttonClick
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.ClickCounter
            Me.Controls.Add(btn)
            buttonTop += 20
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)

        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Did you select {0} ?", btn.Text), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then

            'Yes clicked. Add 1 to counter and show next screen. ???

        Else

            'No clicked. Return to screen to make proper selection.

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ClickCounter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim btn As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)

        Dim usage As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        If btn Is Nothing Then Return

        If Not usage.ContainsKey(btn.Name) Then

            usage.Add(btn.Name, 0)
            usage(btn.Name) += 1

        End If


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is this a web app or windows app?

Comment: winforms, i added the tag

Answer (score 0):

For each action your control allows, you'll have to add 1 to your count. So, create a global variable, either in a module with a shared variable. A dictionary is the right way to go, but you don't have to try to give it a length as it's mutable. My VB is a little rusty, but you should get the gist.

```
'In your button click event

Dim usage As Dictionary(string, integer) = new Dictionary(string, Integer)

If usage.ContainsKey("myButtonName") then
    usage("myButtonName") += 1
Else
    usage.add("myButtonName", 1)
end if
```

Your control's name will be the key and the count will be the value.

Comment: It is telling me "Expression is not a valid method" for the Else statement.

Comment: @user3029953 I forgot the .add. That should work now.

Comment: I have edited my code to what I think is appropriate. Can you have a look? I posted above with an edit.

Comment: @user3029953 Yah, that looks good. You have to use the btn.Name, not "MyButtonName" though. =)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make this a property of the Button controls directly, rather than trying to track in a global variable somewhere.

To do this, I'd inherit a new control from Button, and add a property named something like `TimesClicked`. Then I'd add an event handler (remember: events can have more than one handler) to my new control type that updates that property every time the button is pressed. Now I can replace all my existing buttons with this new control.

If that's too much trouble, I'd still build off of the fact that events can have more than one handler to avoid cluttering regular button response code with the boiler-plate counting code:

```
Private Sub ClickCounter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
    If btn Is Nothing Then Return

    If Not usage.ContainsKey(btn.Name) Then usage.Add(btn.Name, 0)
    usage(btn.Name) += 1
End Sub
```

Either way, your `AddButton()` method would look something like this:

```
Public Sub AddNewButton()

    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100

    For Each item As String In Globals.candidates
        Dim btn As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
        btn.Location = Location
        btn.Text = item
        btn.Width = 150
        AddHandler btn.Clikc, AddressOf Me.ClickCounter
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.buttonClick
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        buttonTop += 20
    Next

End Sub
```

This will also allow you to broaden that ClickCounter method to accept and count uses other types of control and event, without going back to edit change the buttons.

Comment: I think I understand what you proposed, however, I feel as if you're missing something in the example. You are using "usage" that you have not re-declared. I assume Dim usage As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) needs to be with the ClickCounter Sub?

Comment: No. If you put it there, that only exists while the method runs.

Comment: Then I am unsure as to how to access usage if it is not in the scope of ClickCounter... I have updated my question with an edit i believe you were trying to convey. Is it correct, if so, how do I update the clickcounter after Yes is selected?

Comment: You have to declare the `usage` variable somewhere similar to your `Globals` module.